# how to make 'make' append additional standard FLAGS

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

i have a Makefile (that is not really under my control and) that defines a number of variables used by implicit rules:

```
CPPFLAGS := $(CPPFLAGS) -I../../../../modules
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

now, I want to add some additional flags to these variables as *make variables*. Something like:

```
 make CPPFLAGS="-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2" CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

unfortunately this results in *overwriting* the entire CPPFLAGS/CXXLAGS defined in the Makefile, whereas I would like to accumulate them (actually I would like to *append* the externally set flags, even though the above code clearly tries to *prepend*)

For whatever reasons, specifying these variables as *environment variables* (instead of *make variables*) works:

```
 CPPFLAGS="-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2" CXXFLAGS="-g -O2" make
```

now for external reasons, i'm having a hard time passing those flags via envvars (and instead need *make vars*).

So what is the *proper* way to add compiler flags used by implicit rules? Both *overwriting* **and** *accumulating* variables strike me as a common task for Makefiles; there *must* be some way to do this...I've searched the [make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) but haven't found anything!

A simplistic approach is obviously to introduce some helper variable:

```
 CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 $(EXTRA_CXXFLAGS)
```

and then set this helper variable from outside:

```
 make EXTRA_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

But: is there a *standard name* for such helper variable? (If so, which one? where is that documented??) Even better, is there an other variable that is *automatically* added to implicit rules (so i don't have to manually append the FLAGS?)

What is the reason why both variants for accumulating variables in my original Makefile work *only* with envvars, and not with make vars?

Answer (score 12):

**Environment** variables [can be modified](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html#Environment) within `makefile` using normal assignments. And it is common to set variables like `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` which can be appended (or modified in some way) in `makefile`, in the environment:

```
CPPFLAGS="-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2" CXXFLAGS="-g -O2" make
```

As opposite, variables set in `make` **command line**, [cannot be modified](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html#Overriding) within `makefile` using normal assignments. Such way you can set variables which used as some switch within `makefile`:

```
make V=1
```

Example of *Makefile*:

```
V=0 # Will be overriden by variable set in `make` command line
ifneq ($(V),0)
# output some debug information
endif
```

The only way to override variable set in command line is using [override directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Override-Directive.html#Override-Directive):

```
override CPPFLAGS := $(CPPFLAGS) -I../../../../modules # Will append string to variable, even if it set by command line

override CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 # Similar but in the simpler form
```

---

**Modifying `CXXFLAGS` and other `*FLAGS` variables**

Suppose concrete `makefile` allows user to affect flags (that is, it doesn't hardcode them using direct assignment such `CXXFLAGS := -g`). And you want to affect on the flags.

1. Normal way is to set **environment variable** which will *prepend* flags set in the `makefile` itself. These additional flags, set by the `makefile`, are needed for correct compilation and linking.
2. However, you can try to override whole flags using variable set in the **command line**. In that case nobody garantees you don't *suddenly broke the compilation*, but it may work.
3. As for *appending* flags.. Well, it is normally needed for *overwrite* flags set by `makefile` (otherwise prepending flags using environment variable is sufficient). Because of that, any garantees will be vanished again. So, why do not use the previos way (setting whole flags via command line variable assignment)? At least, if something will go wrong, you will definitely know that problem is with you flags, not with ones set by `makefile`.

Comment: This doesn't allow for overriding entirely from the command line but does support the command line prepending/appending.

Comment: @EtanReisner: `override A := 1` perfectly overrides any assignment to `A` in the command line.

Comment: Yes, but that's the opposite of what I meant. The OP asked for ways to append/prepend *and* override from the command line. The default mode is override this changes it to override *or* append/prepend if the makefile is written for it. But you can't support both at the same time in a simple fashion like this (it should be possible with an extra variable and some calls to `$(origin)`, etc. though).

Comment: @EtanReisner: I think I catch your point (and OP one). See added section  about modifying `*FLAGS` variables.

Comment: That's sort of it yes. This is why the autotools have internal versions for use by the project and leave the make standard variables for the user (and why the autotools and other projects use the `EXTRA_*FLAGS` variables for this too). (Also whether the env vars append or prepend depends on how the makefile is written not an inherent property of using the environment. Not to mention that make has the `-e` flag which makes environment variables behave like command line variables and override.)